# Couldn´t access the designated node with cascaded xpath query

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I´ve a XML structur like the following as a SimpleXMLElement:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phonebooks>
    <phonebook name="phonebook">
        ...
        <contact>
            <carddav_uid>70ad8a26-21ab-4b42-b641-44a7667e802a</carddav_uid>
            <telephony>
                <number id="0" type="work">05171290</number>
                <number id="1" type="work">05171291919</number>
                <number id="2" type="work">05171292000</number>
                <number id="3" type="work">05171292010</number>
                <number id="4" type="work">05171292245</number>
                <number id="5" type="work">05171292313</number>
                <number id="6" type="work">05171292383</number>
                <number id="7" type="work">05171292617</number>
                <number id="8" type="work">05171292761</number>
            </telephony>
            <person>
                <realName>ACME Company</realName>
            </person>
        </contact>
        ...
    </phonebook>
</phonebooks>
```

The goal is, if the carddav_uid primarily and secondly the phone number match, then this phone number should be added certain attributes. The first criterion is the carddav_uid, as the phone number can occur in several contacts (e.g. different family members with the same landline number)

Finding the right contact is easy:

```
if ($contact = $xmlTargetPhoneBook->xpath(sprintf('//contact[carddav_uid = "%s"]', $uid))) {
```

I thought it would be easier to search for the right phone number in the node with xpath instead of looping through the structure:

```
if ($contact = $xmlTargetPhoneBook->xpath(sprintf('//contact[carddav_uid = "%s"]', $uid))) {
    if ($phone = $contact[0]->xpath(sprintf('/telephony/number[text() = "%s"]', $number))) {
        // check for debugging 
        print_r($phone);
        /*
        $phone->addAttribute($attribute = $value);
        */
    }
}
```

But I receive nothing:

```
Array
(
)
```

Did I think wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/telephony/number` selects from the root of the document. To select from the context item (the `contact` element), use `./telephony/number` or simply `telephony/number`

Comment: Thank you - I found that out myself in the meantime:

Comment: If the answer is correct then it's useful to other readers to mark it as accepted, even if you had already solved the problem.

Comment: Would you be so kind to help me with the opposite way? I select all nodes <number> that contain certain attributes: `$numbers = $xmlPhonebook->xpath('//number[@attrib_1 or @attribute_2]');` In addition, I have to determine the node carddav_uid or its contents in each case. But `$parentNode = $numbers[0]->xpath("ancestor::*[contact]/*");` delivers me all contacts but not the specific ancestor.

Comment: If you have a new question, it works best in SO to raise it as a new question, not as a comment on an answer to a previous question,